# How do you add a range of numbers in python

Tags: python

I have a list of odd numbers but I still need to add them:

```
for n in range(100, 200):
   if n % 2 == 1:
       print sum([n])
```

Comment: You only want to sum the odd numbers in the list?

Comment: Note: `range(100, 200)` is not list of odd number, it has all number from `100 to 199`.

Comment: `sum([n])` makes a list whose only element is the single number `n`, then evaluates the sum of that list, producing `n` again. That's not what you want; you need to keep track of the sum of all the odd numbers you've gone through so far.

Comment: @user2357112 no it is not works like this read Sberry's answer he explained from fundamental also covered how to use `sum()` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are looking to sum the odd numbers in the range of 100 to 200, then the most straight forward way would be:

```
sum(range(101, 200, 2))
```

Start at 101 (odd), go till 199 (odd) and increment by 2 so that each number is odd.  For instance,

```
>>> range(101, 110)
[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
```

Then you can just sum them.

If you have a preexisting list of numbers then either of the two following methods should fit your need:

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 11, 15, 20, 21]
>>> sum(filter(lambda x: x % 2, nums))
62
>>> sum(num for num in nums if num % 2)
62
```

And this is probably what you were trying to do:

```
>>> total = 0
>>> for num in nums:
...     if num % 2:
...          total += num
...
>>> total
62
```

Comment: `sum(filter(lambda x: x % 2, nums))` could be replace by `sum(nums[: : 2])` Correct? Which one you prefer?

Comment: No, my example was showing numbers that were not in a particular pattern of odd, even, odd, even, odd.  So slicing like this will not work.

Answer (score 5):

[The sum of all numbers from 1 to N (inclusive)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) is N * (N + 1) / 2.

```
def sum_all(N):
    return N * (N + 1) // 2
```

The sum of all even numbers from 1 to N (inclusive) is double the sum of all numbers from 1 to N//2.

```
def sum_even(N):
    return sum_all(N // 2) * 2
```

The sum of all odd numbers from 1 to N (inclusive) is the difference of these.

```
def sum_odd(N):
    return sum_all(N) - sum_even(N)
```

Finally, the sum of all odd numbers between a and b is the sum of all odd numbers from 1 to b minus the sum of all odd numbers from 1 to a - 1.

```
def sum_odd_range(a, b):
    return sum_odd(b) - sum_odd(a - 1)
```

To answer the original question:

```
print sum_odd_range(100, 199)
```

Note that unlike solutions using sum(), these are O(1) and will be arbitrarily faster for larger inputs.